# Add text inside circuit component in circuitikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border={1mm}]{standalone}

\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)to [R,o-o](3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

How can I add a text inside circuit component like figure below?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `name` to name a compenent then you add what you want on it

```
\documentclass[border={1mm}]{standalone}

\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)to [R,o-o,name=R](3,0);
\node at (R){a};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```